# Save generic images from XML nodes

Tags: django, xml-parsing

I'm trying to update my records using XML...so far the first part of the task is done....what I'm wondering is how to get my images onto the saved object (I'm using imagekit for the image handling BTW).  My models look like this:

```
class Photo(ImageModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    num_views = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class IKOptions:
        spec_module = 'my_app.specs'
        cache_dir = 'photos'
        image_field = 'original_image'
        save_count_as = 'num_views'

class Room(models.Model):
    ...
    images = generic.GenericRelation('Photo', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

The XML that I'm using for this is as below:

```
<room>
    <sq_ft>...</sq_ft>
    <size>...</size>
    <bedrooms>...</bedrooms>
    <images>
        <image>photos/IMG_3406.JPG</image>
        <image>photos/IMG_3416.JPG</image>
        <image>photos/IMG_3409.JPG</image>
    </images>
</room>
```

My question is how to get the images for a given room when looping through the XML file and save them against that record.

**UPDATE 1**
I've tried this bit so far:

```
if room.getElementsByTagName('image'):
    photo = ""
    for v in room.getElementsByTagName('images'):
        photo = v.childNodes[0].nodeValue
        room_photo = Photo.objects.create(content_object = room, 
            object_id = room.id, original_image = photo)
```

This does save the photo (somewhat), but then the `original_image` field is always blank, meaning that I'm doing something wrong in the above piece of code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out as the solution finally:

```
imagelist = room.getElementsByTagName('image')
if imagelist:
    for child in imagelist:
        photo = child.childNodes[0].nodeValue
        room_photo = Photo.objects.create(content_object = room, 
                    object_id = room.id, original_image = photo)
```

Thought this might help someone with a similar problem later on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [xml_models](http://djangorestmodel.sourceforge.net/)?  Not sure if it's exactly right for you because I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking.  However, it does take care of relationships with models that use XML very smoothly, so may solve your problem incidentally :-)

I *think* xml_models will work for you.  Let me know!

Comment: This looks a bit interesting....I'll see if I can use this in the app...though I really wanted to know how to handle the problem without resorting to adding another app as I'd already come up with a script to do the updating....the handling of the images is what is bothering me.  I'll keep you posted though

Comment: Just figured out the problem...though I wish I'd known about xml_models before I wrote a long script to do this.  Thnx for the help godswearhats

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn't help with the problem.